# RNN/GRU Increasing validation loss but decreasing mean absolute error

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, loss, tensorflow-probability, overfitting-underfitting

I am new to deep learning and I try to implement an RNN (with 2 GRU layers).
At first, the network seems to do it's job quite fine. However, I am currently trying to understand the loss and accuracy curve. I attached the pictures below. The dark-blue line is the training set and the cyan line is the validation set.
After 50 epochs the validation loss increases. My assumption is that this indicates overfitting. However, I am unsure why the validation mean absolute error still decreases. Do you maybe got an idea?

One idea I had in mind was that this could be caused by some big outliers in my dataset. Thus I already tried to clean it up. I also tried to scale it properly. I also added a few dropout layers for further regularization (rate=0.2). However these are just normal dropout layers because cudnn does not seem to support recurrent_dropout from tensorflow.

Remark: I am using the negative log-likelihood as loss function and a tensorflow probability distribution as the output dense layer.

Any hints what I should investigate?
Thanks in advance

[image: probabilistic]

Edit: I also attached the non-probabilistic plot as recommended in the comment. Seems like here the mean-absolute-error behaves normal (does not improve all the time).
[image: non-probabilistic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the outputs of your model? It sounds pretty strange that you're using the negative log-likelihood (which basically "works" with distributions) as the loss function but the MAE as a metric, which is suited for deterministic continuous values.

I don't know what is your task and perhaps this is meaningful in your specific case, but perhaps the strange behavior comes out from there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As you already guessed my output is a Distribution object. The purpose is to predict the next entry in a time-series and it's uncertainty.
However, actually I got no idea which metric might be suitable for this purpose.
I will also try to test how my model behaves if I remove all probabilistic parts

Comment: Consider that if you mean you're going to predict a next entry that is a continuous deterministic value, you may want to just recast the problem as a regression one. If instead at each step you have a defined distribution and you want to approximate it, probably a good metric could be for instance the Kullback-Leibler divergence. I've never actually dealt with the second case, which seems to me pretty uncommon.

Comment: Yes, It's the first case (continous deterministict value).
Sorry just to get you right: If you are talking about casting it to a regression problem, do you mean removing the RNN(LSTM) Layers and replacing it via Dense Layers?

Btw: Just removed the probabilistic layers and started training. Will provide some feedback as soon as I got some results

Comment: You can definitely keep the RNN architecture, but you need a proper loss function (MSE for instance, instead of the negative log-likelihood). This https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/ could be a good source to clarify any doubt.

Comment: just marked this as the answer. So far I do not have exactly identified the problem but it seems to be only occuring due to my probabilistic transformation in combination with the MAE loss